# What is the private key format?

Tags: wallet, private-key, wallet-import-format, private-key-format

I wasn't aware of a private key format, however numerous stackoverflow posts hint towards a formatting of some kind

[Format of private key](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/46443/format-of-private-key)

[Which private key format is this?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/23247/which-private-key-format-is-this)

[What encoding or format is the private key in Dumpprivkey?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/21859/what-encoding-or-format-is-the-private-key-in-dumpprivkey)

And looking at [iancoleman/bip39's website](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/), indeed the private key changes as you change the coin, implying that there is at least a format that takes into account version bytes.

However, using [hdkey](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/hdkey/blob/master/lib/hdkey.js) in js I am unable to reproduce this format, or even the "32-byte big-endian secret parameter" Pieter Wuille describes in the last example.

```
var bip39 = require('bip39');
var hdkey = require('hdkey');    

const mnemonic = 'thunder purchase pave tower lecture upgrade supreme half kid fitness tray shove'
const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic); //creates seed buffer
console.log('mnemonic: ' + mnemonic);

const root = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(seed);
const masterPrivateKey = root.privateKey.toString('hex');

const addrnode = root.derive("m/0'/0");
console.log('addrnodePublicKey: '+ addrnode._publicKey.toString('hex'))
console.log('addernodePrivateKey: ' + addrnode._privateKey.toString('hex'))
```

What is the detailed private key format? What does it consist of, how do you derive it from a standard private key? What is it used for compared to the unformatted private key?

Answer (score 3):

The format you use depends on how you need to use the private key. Your code produces a raw hex private key, without formatting.

```
$ node index.js
mnemonic: thunder purchase pave tower lecture upgrade supreme half kid fitness tray shove
addrnodePublicKey: 02ceb48796223dc3777fe210a2034059b5e39b3743e59d62f75ef07a32f8440caf
addernodePrivateKey: 310fe2e677a3ad28acb91d2645bb33882f015ab11e59dce9d2a72905979e3cb6
```

### Raw Private Key

A private key (in bitcoin, i.e. `ECDSA SECP256K1`) is a 32 byte number between `0x1` and `0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFE BAAE DCE6 AF48 A03B BFD2 5E8C D036 4140`.

For example:

`0C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D`

### Wallet Input Format (WIF)

However, wallet software typically uses the **Wallet Input Format (WIF)** to make it easier to copy over. It uses `base58check` encoding so it avoids ambiguous characters (like 0 and O), it is shorter, and includes a checksum in case of typos. For example:

`5HueCGU8rMjxEXxiPuD5BDku4MkFqeZyd4dZ1jvhTVqvbTLvyTJ`

#### WIF Conversion

The process of converting a raw private key to WIF is outline here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format:

- Take a private key

  `0C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D`
- Add a 0x80 byte in front of it for mainnet addresses or 0xef for testnet addresses. Also add a 0x01 byte at the end if the private key will correspond to a compressed public key

  `800C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D`
- Perform SHA-256 hash on the extended key

  `8147786C4D15106333BF278D71DADAF1079EF2D2440A4DDE37D747DED5403592`
- Perform SHA-256 hash on result of SHA-256 hash

  `507A5B8DFED0FC6FE8801743720CEDEC06AA5C6FCA72B07C49964492FB98A714`
- Take the first 4 bytes of the second SHA-256 hash, this is the checksum

  `507A5B8D`
- Add the 4 checksum bytes from point 5 at the end of the extended key from point 2

  `800C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D507A5B8D`
- Convert the result from a byte string into a base58 string using Base58Check encoding. This is the Wallet Import Format

  `5HueCGU8rMjxEXxiPuD5BDku4MkFqeZyd4dZ1jvhTVqvbTLvyTJ`

**Potential node.js resources:**

- https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bs58check
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-hash

Comment: ```% echo 0C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D | bx base58check-encode -v 128```
**5HueCGU8rMjxEXxiPuD5BDku4MkFqeZyd4dZ1jvhTVqvbTLvyTJ**

Comment: ```% echo 0C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D01 | bx base58check-encode -v 128```
**KwdMAjGmerYanjeui5SHS7JkmpZvVipYvB2LJGU1ZxJwYvP98617**

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere I answered this already, but coldn't find it anymore... I was confused on the different keys as well, and created [image: this graphic] to have a clearer picture: